# Error when restoring 9.5 pgdump files on 9.6 postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

We have been using 9.5 postgres.

And we use pgdump to get backup files from that database and then subsequently use it to restore on a 9.6 postgres.

We were unable to restore successfully. Usually the minor version upgrade does not mean backwards breaking.

I am wondering what's the issue causing us to be unable to successfully restore on a 9.6 database.

We need to do so just in case we need to restore from archived data backups.

Comment: Can you tell us what error you're getting? And what command lines you're using for `pg_dump` and the restore?

Comment: Are you trying to restore a logical dump or a custom one?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** command you used to take the backup the **exact** command you use to restore the backup and the **exact** error message you got. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You need to use `pg_dump` from the 9.6 installation to create the dump from the 9.5 database.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, what do you mean by use the 9.6 installation to create the dump from the 9.5 database? you mean i need to install 9.6 on the same machine and then use the 9.6 pg_dump while connected to the 9.5 database?

Comment: Yes. You could also use a 9.6 installation on a different machine.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe so you mean I can use the command line running 9.6 on *one* machine, then pg_dump from 9.5 running on a *second* machine? The output file should be on the first machine right?

Comment: Right, exactly. You use `pg_dump -h <hostname> -p <port>` to connect to a different database server.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same error when upgrading from 9.3 to 9.6.
The restore failed every time I tried but the dump was successful.

My solution to this problem was not to use the custom format! Instead I used the plain format. So I tried plain format with file extension sql, with utf8 encoding as user postgres. And obviously don't forget to include pre-data, data and post-data because otherwise your restore won't be complete. This works perfectly.

If your dump is ok, also try a full vacuum before the dump. If the vacuum is not ok, this might be your problem.

Comment: This solution worked well for me.  This is the equivalent of a full dump (schema + tables + sequences + data).

Answer (score 2):

To Take Dump

```
pg_dump --username=postgres --format=c --file=e:/testdbdump.sql testdb
```

OR

```
pg_dump -U username databasename >>sqlfile.sql
```

To Restore

```
pg_restore --username=postgres --dbname=testdb<d:\sqlfile.sql

pg_restore --username=postgres --dbname=testdb <d:\sqlfile.sql



pg_restore --username=postgres --dbname=testdb <d:\testDBApr18.sql

pg_restore --username=postgres --dbname=testdb <c:\Backup\testdbDBApr18.sql
```

// PG DUMP & RESTORE THAT WORKS FOR ME

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost --format=c testdb > db_dump_file.dump

pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -v -d testdb db_dump_file.dump
```

Comment: these are working for me.
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost --format=c testdb > db_dump_file.dump

pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -v -d testdb db_dump_file.dump